# passing optional arguments as strings or arays

Tags: python, parameter-passing

I have this function which works as expected

```
import numpy as np
def my_fun(X, Weights = None):
     if Weights is None:
            np.random.normal(0,1,1)
     else:
            Weights + 1
```

Hence I can call my_fun using my_fun(my_X) or my_fun(my_X,Weights = my_weights) where my_weights is an array.

However, I need to include a third option to my_fun, and ideally I would like to pass the argument as an string. Something like this.

```
import numpy as np
    def my_fun(X, Weights = None):
         if Weights is None:
                np.random.normal(0,1,1)
         elif Weights == 'My_string':
                np.random.beta(1,1,1)
         else:
                Weights + 1
```

If I try to call my_fun as my_fun(my_X,Weights = 'a') then I get the following error: **FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead...**

Any thoughts how to re-shape my_fun?

Comment: Your code doesn't cause that error. Do you have a working example?

Comment: @Radio- you are right, I just posted a simplified version of my original function, and in this version there is no error. i need to check what is causing the error in my original def

Comment: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6784 may shed some light on the warning.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't see the purpose of your `X`, you are never using it in the function. Why send it then?

Also you need `return` in your function. What you want to return? it's not clear. Maybe something along the lines.

```
def my_fun(X, Weights = None):
     if Weights is None:
           X = np.random.normal(0,1,1)
     elif Weights == 'My_string':
            X = np.random.beta(1,1,1)
     else:
            Weights + 1
     return Weights,X

print( my_fun([1,2,3],Weights = 'My_string') )
```

Comment: I tried to simplified my original function and only show what I thought it was generating the error that I am getting. In my function I work with an object, so i only modify the object using my_fun, so I dont need to return anything. I will check what is causing error in my original function and will update my question then.

Comment: @user1571823 be careful with the `local`, `global` variable declaration then.